# Engine to generate dynamic reports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, report

I need to implement an engine to generate reports dynamically with *JasperReports*. My reports are very simple; basically listing.

So, when users click on a button to generate the report, the app will open a dialog with all columns available for them to choose the ones that they want to see.

Anyone know any engine that works this way according to these needs?

Comment: You can use [JasperReports API](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/) or [DynamicJasper API](http://dynamicjasper.com/documentation-examples/api-docs/) or [DynamicReports API](http://apidocs.dynamicreports.org/)

Answer (score 0):

http://dynamicjasper.com/
The closest one I know of is this project.  I didnt use it because it did not fit my needs, but give it a shot.